# Protected File Download Script. Almost there

Tags: php

I have a file that users will purchase via paypal, clickbank and paydotcom. I have to host the file's download page on my server.

I've placed the file in a directory outside my public_html folder. The folder is on the same level as public_html and called "download" for example.

The script below is supposed to do that, but I have two problems with it...

1) It doesn't seem too secure. just check for a payment confirmation token on the querystring?

2) I can't the $path variable to point to the download folder without including my site.com public folder in the path. For example, when I echo $path, I get

```
/home/myuser/public_html/mysite.com
```

But I need it to resolve to

```
/home/myuser/download/myprotectedfile.zip
```

I'm sure there is a more secure or clever way to do this, so I'm asking...

```
<?php

// place this code inside a php file and call it f.e. "download.php"
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path2file/"; // change the path to fit your websites document structure
$fullPath = $path.$_GET['download_file'];

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
        header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
        break;
        default;
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    }
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;
// example: place this kind of link into the document where the file download is offered:
// <a href="download.php?download_file=some_file.pdf">Download here</a>
?>
```

The problem I'm having in getting this to work is the the value of $path includes my site.com reference, but the download directory is outside site.com. I need to get a reference up a level in order to point to the directory that holds the download file.

Also, as I stated earlier, I'm not sure how to do this (other than checking for an expected querystring value in a manner that's secure)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of reading the file into a buffer with a loop, why don't you use the readfile function ? http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#function.readfile.examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the parent directory shortcut `../` in your `$path` or the [`dirname`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function like:

```
$parent_dir = dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) );
// first dirname is the directory of this file, second goes up one level, etc.
```

BTW, beware of indicating the path in your URL, one could read other files (like configuration files or ohter private files) by changing it to `download.php?download_file=../../private/bank_certificate.pem`. You should use [`realpath`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to get the absolute path of the file and compare it to an "authorized for download" file list.

Comment: OK, I can use this to get a pointer to my directory where the file is stored. I'm just not sure the rest of my code is correct now. I keep getting an error stating..."Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..."

Comment: 1. beware `dirname` returns the path as a string, not a file descriptor on the directory 
2. This warning means that you already sent some output. It can happen if you `echo` 'ed something or when you have blank lines or whitespaces at the beginning / end of  your php files (like before your `<?php` or after your `?>` in another included file).

Comment: Warning. I found that this script has a security issue. If someone feeds it with path to secure file the script allows to download it. Example if download_file=../includes/dbconnect.php you can loose your db password. Thread $download_file before passing it to the script.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the point of the paragraph I wrote just below the code example.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to consider the path like a normal directory path, not a web one. so to go up a level simply "../" e.g.

if you structure is like this

/path2file/inhere.pdf
/public_html/download.php

the path to the file would simply be from download.php "../path2file/inhere.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

well if `public_html` is your doc root then you should be able to get the path to download would be

`realpath($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].'/../download');`

Answer (score -1):

Custom coding may not be the best solution these days for a file download script. Check out Drupal which has file download modules, that can be integrated with its Clickbank module as well:
http://drupal.org/project/clickbank_ipn