# Php code to download pdf file from server not working

Tags: php

I have written a code to download pdf file from server, but the code is not working and I cant even see the errors
This is the code which I am using.

```
// place this code inside a php file and call it f.e. "download.php"
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/product_images/"; // change the path to fit your     websites document structure
fullPath = $path.$_REQUEST['download_file'];

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
$fsize = filesize($fullPath);
$path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
switch ($ext) {
    case "pdf":
    header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff.     extensions
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");     // use 'attachment' to force a download
    break;
    default;
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
}
header("Content-length: $fsize");
header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
while(!feof($fd)) {
    $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
    echo $buffer;
}
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;
// example: place this kind of link into the document where the file download is offered:
// <a href="download.php?download_file=some_file.pdf">Download here</a>
?>
```

I am fetching the file from database and this is my download link which I am using on my site

```
<div style="padding-left:320px; padding-top:5px;"><a href="<?php echo URL ?>download.php?download_file=<?php echo $prod_details['specification_pdf']?>">
<img src="<?php       echo URL ?>images/download_pdf.png" /></a></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help me in resolving this problem

Comment: In line two there's no `$` before `fullPath`.

Comment: fullpath is defined as variable

Comment: Have you changed "$path" in 2nd line to your files directory?

Comment: once you fix `$fullPath`, realize that you're allowing malicious remote users to download **ANY** file on your server that they know the path for. If you do not understand how/why, then I suggest you first start learning about basic php scripting security

Comment: As Marc mentioned, this will cause LFI (Local File Inclusion) attacks on your site, make sure that in download.php you also check if such document file is available in DB.

Comment: thanks marc for the suggestion can you tell me from where can I learn php scripting and can you suggest any changes to this code which is secured and works

Comment: You are also missing a $ infront of URL where you are echoing out

Comment: @RajanMehta Take a look at these questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228750/help-understand-this-php-code-download-file), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069521/error-in-this-download-code-pls-check-this-and-give-me-the-solution), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258009/protected-file-download-script-almost-there). They all copied the same block of code that you did. The answers to those questions will help you make your code more secure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As say @lasar missing $ in line 2 could be the problem. 
I adapt (and test) your code to be more secure (see basename) and direct (see readfile):

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/product_images/"; // change the path to fit your     websites document structure
$fullPath = $path.basename($_REQUEST['download_file']);

if (is_readable ($fullPath)) {
$fsize = filesize($fullPath);
$path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
switch ($ext) {
    case "pdf":
    header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff.     extensions
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");     // use 'attachment' to force a download
    break;
    default;
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
}
header("Content-length: $fsize");
header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
readfile($fullPath);
exit;
} else {
        die("Invalid request");
}
// example: place this kind of link into the document where the file download is offered:
// <a href="download.php?download_file=some_file.pdf">Download here</a>
```

ADD

- see [readfile manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) for a good explanation of headers to
  download files
- **REMEMBER** due it's nature PHP is well know to damage binary file download, remeber to keep **<?php** always in 1st line and avoid close tag **?>** in PHP-only files

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.